# VBS script keeping old values even though I changed them

Tags: vbscript

I am running the script below to keep my computer from going to sleep:

```
set wsc = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Do
    'Five minutes
    WScript.Sleep(5*60*1000)
    wsc.SendKeys("{NUMLOCK 2}")
Loop
```

I am trying to change the key to replace the key to be sent form <kbd>NumLock</kbd> to <kbd>F8</kbd> but no matter what I put in the script, once I save it and run it, it keeps sending <kbd>NumLock</kbd>. Do you know why?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel.  I have written many programs to keep my machine awake.  None of them work as well as this [free gem](https://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/).  I KNOW it doesn't answer your actual question which is why it is posted as a comment.

Comment: Or [PowerToys Awake](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/awake). As for the script, can you share exactly how your script looks after the change?

Comment: Presumably you checked the file and it now contains `F8` instead of `NumLock`. That is, your script hasn't become read-only. If so, then what you describe implies that you're running another copy of the script that hasn't been edited. How are you running the script?

Comment: BTW, `F8` doesn't look like a good choice for a wake up key. You should use something like Ctrl, Shift, or Alt so there's little to no chance of interacting with a running program.

Comment: If you still need help, can you edit your post and add the new script and location of where it is stored and also how you run the script?